# subquery for ranking is not giving desired results Sybase ASE

Tags: ranking, sap-ase

SQL QUERY with ranking functions:

```
        select availability_stat from (select availability_stat, row_number() 
        over (partition by sop_ckey order by 
        case availability_stat when 'ONLINE' then 1 
        when 'NEARLINE' then 2 when 'OFFLINE' then 3 end) 
        as rownumber from arc_address where study_ckey = 849) 
        as arc_address_with_rownumber 
        where rownumber = 1 group by availability_stat
```

OUTPUT:

```
    study_ckey|sop_ckey|availability_stat|rownumber|
    ----------|--------|-----------------|---------|
           849|     955|NEARLINE         |        1|
           849|     955|ONLINE           |        3|
           849|     955|OFFLINE          |        2|
           849|     957|NEARLINE         |        1|
           849|     960|NEARLINE         |        1|
           849|     960|ONLINE           |        2|
           849|     963|NEARLINE         |        1|
           849|     963|OFFLINE          |        2|
           849|     971|NEARLINE         |        1|
           849|     971|ONLINE           |        2|
           849|     973|NEARLINE         |        1|
           849|     973|OFFLINE          |        2|
```

SYBASE QUERY tried with subquery:

```
        select aa.study_ckey,aa.sop_ckey,  aa.availability_stat,
       (select count(distinct availability_stat) 
        from arc_address aa2
        where aa2.sop_ckey = aa.sop_ckey
        and aa2.availability_stat < aa.availability_stat 
        or aa2.availability_stat = aa.availability_stat ) as rownumber
       from arc_address aa 
        where aa.study_ckey = 849 
        order by sop_ckey
```

OUTPUT:

```
study_ckey|sop_ckey|availability_stat|rownumber|
----------|--------|-----------------|---------|
       849|     955|NEARLINE         |        1|
       849|     955|ONLINE           |        3|
       849|     955|OFFLINE          |        2|
       849|     957|NEARLINE         |        1|
       849|     960|NEARLINE         |        1|
       849|     960|ONLINE           |        2|
       849|     963|NEARLINE         |        1|
       849|     963|OFFLINE          |        2|
       849|     971|NEARLINE         |        1|
       849|     971|ONLINE           |        2|
       849|     973|NEARLINE         |        1|
       849|     973|OFFLINE          |        2|
```

The ranking is not happening as expected, i.e.

ONLINE - 1 ,
NEARLINE -2,
OFFLINE - 3
probably I am not using case statement here, but the case statement even worsens the result set. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved the same and sharing the solution

```
        select sop_ckey,availability_stat, case when availability_stat = 'ONLINE' then 1
                             when availability_stat = 'NEARLINE' then 2
                             when availability_stat = 'OFFLINE' then 3
                         end as rank_value
        into #tmp
        from arc_address aa1 where study_ckey = 849
        group by sop_ckey,availability_stat

      
        select availability_stat
            from (
                    select availability_stat,(select 1 + count(distinct t2.availability_stat)
                    from #tmp t2
                    where t2.sop_ckey = t1.sop_ckey and 
                    t2.rankvalue < t1.rankvalue) as new_rank
                    from #tmp t1
                 )
        as arc_address_with_rownumber
        where  newrank = 1
        group by availability_stat
```